# Regex for a (twitter-like) hashtag that allows non-ASCII characters

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter, hashtag, unicode-string

I want a regex to match a simple hashtag like that in twitter (e.g. #someword). I want it also to recognize non standard characters (like those in Spanish, Hebrew or Chinese).

This was my initial regex: `(^|\s|\b)(#(\w+))\b`
--> but it doesn't recognize non standard characters.
Then, I tried using [XRegExp.js](http://xregexp.com/), which worked, but ran too slowly.

Any suggestions for how to do it?

Comment: Word boundary can't be simply used with unicode. see http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Default_Word_Boundaries

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually I found this: [twitter-text.js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js) useful link, which is basically how twitter solve this problem.

Comment: The excellent repo moved here : https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js where it was aggregated with a list for all languages : https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text

Answer (score 3):

With native JS regexes that don't support unicode, your only option is to explicitly enumerate characters that can end the tag and match everything else, for example:

```
> s = "foo #הַתִּקְוָה. bar"
"foo #הַתִּקְוָה. bar"
> s.match(/#(.+?)(?=[\s.,:,]|$)/)
["#הַתִּקְוָה", "הַתִּקְוָה"]
```

The `[\s.,:,]` should include spaces, punctuation and whatever else can be considered a terminating symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`#([^#]+)[\s,;]*`

Explanation: This regular expression will search for a `#` followed by one or more non-`#` characters, followed by 0 or more spaces, commas or semicolons.

```
var input = "#hasta #mañana #babהַ";
var matches = input.match(/#([^#]+)[\s,;]*/g);
```

Result:

```
["#hasta ", "#mañana ", "#babהַ"]
```

EDIT - Replaced \b for word boundary

Comment: The `?` after the `+` just means "don't be too greedy" when trying to match all the non-hash characters.

Comment: With the '?' it doesn't match '#mañana' and without it regonize '#mañana baby' as one hashtag. Not to mention Hebrew - doesn't recognize at all.

Comment: Word boundary `\b` is a zero-length assertion that is true between a word character and a non-word character

Comment: As pointed out \b isn't correct when dealing with non-latin characters. I've revised my answer.  Typically hash-tags do not contain spaces @limlim