# Extract words starting with a particular character from a string

Tags: java, string, extract

I got the following string:

```
 String line = "#food was testy. #drink lots of. #night was fab. #three #four";
```

I want to take `#food` `#drink` `#night` `#three` and `#four` from it.

I tried this code:

```
    String[] words = line.split("#");
    for (String word: words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

But it gives `food was testy`, `drink lots of`, `nigth was fab`, `three` and `four`.

Comment: Why you trying like this. You know the character is "#". So  System.out.println("#"+word);

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`split` will only cuts the whole string at where it founds a *#*. That explain your current result.

You may want to extract the first word of every pieces of string, but the good tool to perform your task is [RegEx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Here how you can achieve it:

```
String line = "#food was testy. #drink lots of. #night was fab. #three #four";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\w+");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output is:

```
#food
#drink
#night
#three
#four
```

The magic happen in "#\w+".

- `#` the pattern start with a #
- `\w` [Matches any letter (a-z, A-Z), number (0-9), or underscore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html).
- `+` Matches one or more consecutive `\w` characters.

So we search for stuff starting with `#` followed by one or more letter, number or underscore.

We use '\\' for '\' because of [Escape Sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

You can play with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oH6nH4/1).

`find` and `group` are explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

- The `find` method scans the input sequence looking for the next subsequence that matches the pattern.
- `group()` returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match.

**[edit]**

The use of `\w` can be an issue if you need to detect accented characters or non-latin characters.

For example in:

> "Bonjour mon #bébé #chat."

The matches will be:

- **#b**
- **#chat**

It depends on what you will accept as possible *hashTag*. But it is an other question and [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics) [discussions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) [exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941861/regex-for-a-twitter-like-hashtag-that-allows-non-ascii-characters) [about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode).

For example, if you want any characters from any language, `#\p{L}+` looks good, but the underscore is not in it...

Comment: This is working fine. but how can i get the Matched word in variable?

Comment: String mtch=matcher.group().toString(); got it using this. :) Thank you alot. Both of You. @Orace and @ Jitesh Ji.

Comment: You did not need the `toString` as the result of `group()` is already a string. Also you have multiple results, you may need to use a container to put them all in it. I will edit my code.

Comment: you said \w matched any letter than why it doesn't run till after the whitespace.?

Comment: i have an arraylist so can i add like this tag_list.add(matcher.group())? and   when if i extract will for-each work? because i have to put the matched words in Sqlite. so i need to do that?

Comment: The solution indeed is: `while (matcher.find()) {  tag_list.add(matcher.group()); }` then you can use the `tag_list`container to retrieve all the tags (with a for-each).

Comment: i done that. Thanks Senior @Orace.  i will need such helps further wherever i stuck. :)

Comment: Ask a new question if you need help. I think this one is complete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435265/accessing-phones-gallery-path-to-create-bitmap-null-pointer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485531/how-can-i-use-regex-to-get-data-from-sqlite

Comment: It does not include @ character in the word. For example, '#my@email.com is my email'. The regex only returns '#my' instead I want it to return complete '#my@email.com'. Any help

Comment: @ZaEeMZaFaR try this pattern: "#[.@\\w]+" and look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the procedure to do ==>

```
   String candidate = "#food was testy. #drink lots of. #night was fab. #three #four";

        String regex = "#\\w+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher m = p.matcher(candidate);
        String val = null;

        System.out.println("INPUT: " + candidate);

        System.out.println("REGEX: " + regex + "\r\n");

        while (m.find()) {
          val = m.group();
          System.out.println("MATCH: " + val);
        }
        if (val == null) {
          System.out.println("NO MATCHES: ");
        }
```

which will give output as follows as i solved the problem at my netbeans IDE and tested the program

```
INPUT: #food was testy. #drink lots of. #night was fab. #three #four

REGEX: #\w+

MATCH: #food

MATCH: #drink

MATCH: #night

MATCH: #three

MATCH: #four
```

you will need the following imports

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

Comment: You will include the space after the word and match the empty one `# ` (with one space).

Comment: ah yes you are correct, going to edit the answer. :)

Comment: You still match `#` alone.